# where do we use JDBC and what is so special about it?

Tags: sql, database, jdbc

if we can get all the data using sql queries directly by writing the query and executing it in postgresql pg3admin then **why do we need to use JDBC** for requesting data. To be explicit where do we use JDBC in practical?

Comment: JDBC connects (C) your Java (J) application to a database (DB).

Comment: JDBC is used to communicate with the dbms server, a programming API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of JDBC is to provide a standard interface for connecting to different DBMS-es.

The goal of SQL is to provide a standard language which can be used to write portable queries across multiple DBMS-es.

So the direct comparison between them is apples and oranges. However from a developer point of view, you can say that JDBC is a way to connect to the DB server, SQL is the way to instruct the DB server to do actual work.

Answer (score 2):

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) says

> JDBC is a Java database connectivity technology (Java Standard Edition
>   platform) from Oracle Corporation. This technology is an API for the
>   Java programming language that defines how a client may access a
>   database. It provides methods for querying and updating data in a
>   database. JDBC is oriented towards relational databases. A
>   JDBC-to-ODBC bridge enables connections to any ODBC-accessible data
>   source in the JVM host environment.

and the same wikipedia says about [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

> SQL Structured Query Language[6][7][8][9]) is a special-purpose
>   programming language designed for managing data held in a relational
>   database management system (RDBMS), or for stream processing in a
>   relational data stream management system (RDSMS).

I think these 2 statements are more than enough to convey the difference but in **layman** terms

> SQL is a standardized query language for requesting information from a
>   database

Mainly used to manipulate the data in database

where as

> (JDBC) is an application program interface
>   (API) specification for connecting programs written in Java to the
>   data in popular databases.

Used to Provide bridge for your java application to access database and then use SQL to manipulate data